# How are sampling frequency of an ADC and switching speed of a multiplexer synchronized?

Tags: multiplexer

In a typical multiplexed system if we set the sampling frequency twice, does that mean the multiplexer switch loops faster like two times? And what controls the speed of multiplexer? (By speed of the MUX I mean the speed of the pivot like switch shown under the Multiplexer diagram below):

[image]

Comment: you also need to consider settling-time of the signal-processing chain. Suppose timeconstant (tau) is 100nanoseconds. That provides 9dB (1 neper) better accuracy. For 12 bit measurement, you need at least 8 Tau or 800 nanoSeconds settlng, thus your ADC rate should not be faster than 1.25 MHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is totally up to you, you have to somehow control and synchronize the tasks of sampling and multiplexing.

**You could use a µC, that triggers each conversion and switches the MUX to the next position after each finished conversion.** OR you could measure multiple data points at one MUX position and only then  switch the input of the MUX. It completly depends on your application.

Let's assume two use cases:

1) **You sample different audio channels, only one at a time:**  You sample with a typical audio sampling frequency of 44,1 kHz. You want to do this for a few seconds or minutes. After that you switch to the next audio input. If you double the sampling frequency you would probably not change the MUX speed, because these two parameters are independent (sampling frequency for your signal quality, MUX frequency for the time slots each input has).

2) **You want to simultaneously capture different channels, e.g. in an oscilloscope:** You always take one sample and immediately switch to the next input channel. Doubling the sampling frequency would require you to also double the MUX frequency, because both frequencies are synchronized.

Comment: Does those two modes have specific names?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Both cases are TDM (Time domain multiplexing) of the ADC. In the first case the time slots are pretty large compared to the sampling frequency, in the second case the timeslots are of a similar length as the sampling period.